# How is this php session control being avoided?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have been struggling with a relatively old php script for uploading images. Someone is uploading images with php code to this admin site and I'm not able to decipher how. This is the code I'm using, relying on php session.

```
require "../../../files/php/config/require.php";

if($_POST){


  $item = new Popup();
  $item->nombre = _post("nombre");
  $item->fecha = _post("fecha");
  $item->descripcion = _post("descripcion");
  $item->is_on = _post_check("is_on");

  if ($_FILES['imagen']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['imagen']['error']);
  }

  $info = getimagesize($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']);
  if ($info === FALSE) {
    die("Unable to determine image type of uploaded imagen");
  }

  if (($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_GIF) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_JPEG) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {
    die("Not a gif/jpeg/png");
  }

  $result = subir($_FILES["imagen"]);
```

This is inside the require.php

```
$local = true;
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.tuviaje.com.ar, http://tuviaje.com.ar");

if (empty($local)) {
    require "config_remote.php";
} else {
    require "config.php";
}

require __ROOT . "files/php/class/functions.php";
require __ROOT . "files/php/class/Alert.php";
require __ROOT . "files/php/class/Entity.php";
require __ROOT . "files/php/class/Object.php";
require __ROOT . "logic/class/Session/User.php";

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user".__HASH])) {
    redirect(__URL . "index.php?loggedOut");
}
$__user = $_SESSION["user".__HASH];
```

...
    function redirect($link) {
        echo 'window.location.href="' . $link . '"';
        exit;
    }

Somehow the isset !isset($_SESSION["user".__HASH]) is being bypassed.

Disclaimer: This is an old admin site for uploading images I'm supposed to fix.

Comment: anything from error reporting/logs?

Comment: The session isn't getting started, you have to start the session before sending any headers. And that means `$_SESSION` shouldn't be set. Looks like something is missing here.

Comment: the session is started, and the session variable is set. So that's not the issue.

Comment: I see a lot of this in the log: script '/var/www/html/xiaoma.php' not found or unable to stat